# Plugin refuses to compile due to COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 test failing

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, centos

This is the following output i keep getting when i run the commands
I'm not sure exactly where im going wrong here. I'm also having issues with boost yum says the boost libraries installed.

```
 cmake teamspeak-connector
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Failed
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:73 (message):
  The compiler /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++ does not fulfill all
  required standards.  Please use a different C++ compiler.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/sampcompiles/samp-tsconnector-1.2.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/sampcompiles/samp-tsconnector-1.2.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: The message indicates that the compiler you are using doesn't support the CXX11 standards that cmake/the project believes it needs. Other than upgrading the compiler (or figuring out if you can tweak the project to not need those features and changing the test) I'm not sure there's anything you can do here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is figure out how to rectify the compiler situation what do I need to compile this with the proper requirements

Comment: A compiler that supports whatever is being tested for as `COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11`. Likely the `-std=c++11` flag. If there are updated devtools packages/version that might help. If not then I don't know.

Comment: `GCC 4.8.2` doesn't have complete `C++11` features and perhaps that is the reason for the error. If that's the case then you can either upgrade your compiler (usually means upgrading the OS) or install a later version of the compiler in a separate location (home dirs or /opt).